# Bar Chart and Issues with Hovering in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am currently working with Plotly in R, attempting to create a bar chart. Below, you can find my data and code.

```
# Generating artificial data
set.seed(42)  # for reproducibility
n <- 50  # Number of data points
dat <- data.frame(
  PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_CODE = factor(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE)),
  revenue_before = runif(n, min = 100, max = 1000),  # Random values for revenue_before
  revenue_after = runif(n, min = 100, max = 1000),   # Random values for revenue_after
  PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_NAME = sample(c("Industry A", "Industry B", "Industry C", "Industry D", "Industry E"), n, replace = TRUE)
)

# Plotting
plt <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_CODE,  y = ~revenue_before, type = 'bar', name = 'Tax rate 1',hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_NAME) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_CODE,  y = ~revenue_after, type = 'bar', name = 'Tax rate 2', hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_NAME) %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ''), 
    yaxis = list(title = ''),
    barmode = 'group',
    title = ' '
  ) %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h'))  # Set legend orientation to horizontal

plt
```

[image]

While the code successfully generates the bar chart, I've encountered a new issue.

Specifically, text appears inside the bars on the chart, which is not the desired outcome.

I only want this text to be visible when hovering over the bars with the mouse, not inside the bars themselves.

Could anyone offer assistance on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `textposition="none"` to remove the text inside the bars and use a `hovertemplate` to get the right hover like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

plt <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_CODE,  y = ~revenue_before, type = 'bar', name = 'Tax rate 1',hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_NAME,
            textposition = "none", hovertemplate = "%{text}") %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_CODE,  y = ~revenue_after, type = 'bar', name = 'Tax rate 2', hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~PRODUCT_INDUSTRY_NAME,
            textposition = "none", hovertemplate = "%{text}") %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = ''), 
    yaxis = list(title = ''),
    barmode = 'group',
    title = ' '
  ) %>%
  layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h'))  # Set legend orientation to horizontal

plt
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works, but now I can see horizontal white lines inside. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could use `bargap=0` to your `layout` function to remove the white lines.